# Editing Startup Processes in Windows Task Manager

Tags: windows, startup, taskmanager

In the `Startup` tab in Windows Task Manager:

[image: startup]

there is a column named `Command line` that gives the exact command being run for each startup process in the list.

I am wondering if there is a way to edit these commands in some way. I'm aware that I can just place a shortcut in the startup folder and disable the relevant process in Task Manager, but this seems like a rather inelegant solution. I assume that there should be some way to edit these startup processes in the Registry Editor or something, but I have been unable to find anything so far. If I have to delete the existing startup process and create a new one then I'm fine with that as well, I would just prefer that the program be run this way rather than through the startup folder.

Comment: Have a look at [AutoRuns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) (of sysinternals heritage, now Microsoft's).

Comment: @dxiv Just wanted to thank you for that recommendation. That program has proved to be very useful for a variety of functions so far. It's basically like task scheduler and command prompt rolled into one, and then made much more powerful. It really is wonderful.